# Using sed to delete some text on multiple files in a directory

Tags: sed

I'm removing the same text from a number of files using

```
sed -n -i '' '/<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>/q;p'  myfile.emlx
```

which works so far.

I understand that I can run this over all the files in the current directory. I tested this using

```
sed -i ''  's/^/\t/'  *.txt
```

and that worked as expected, however when I try

```
sed -n -i '' '/<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>/q;p' *.emlx
```

although the first file is correctly ammended and saved, all the text from all the other files is removed.
I've tried various combinations of -i and -n etc but can't work out my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your approach is that `sed` carries patterns across file boundaries.  You will want to revert to running one `sed` instance per file.

```sh
for file in *.emlx; do
    sed -n -i '' '/<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>/q;p' "$file"
done
```

Quick demo:

```sh
bash$ printf '%s\n' >foo "one" "two" "three"
bash$ printf '%s\n' >bar "four" "five" "six"
bash$ tail *
===> foo <===
one
two
three
===> bar <===
four
five
six
bash$ sed '/two/,/five/d' foo bar
one
six
```

Comment: Of course, as always, `-i ''` is a BSD-ism; on Linux and some other platforms, the syntax is simply `-i` without an argument.